# Is it possible to encode and decode two consequent byte arrays (with unknown sizes) using `abi.encode` and `abi.decode`?

Tags: solidity, arrays, abi, bytes, decoding

Is it possible to encode and decode two consequent bytes using `abi.encode` and `abi.decode` (as following)?

```
bytes memory data = abi.encode(data1, data2);
// later on
(bytes memory data1_recovered, bytes memory data2_recovered) = abi.decode(data, bytes, bytes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work. The following example concatenates two strings.

```
function foo(string memory a, string memory b) public view returns (string memory) {
    bytes memory data1 = bytes(a);
    bytes memory data2 = bytes(b);
    bytes memory data = abi.encode(data1, data2);
    return bar(data);
}

function bar(bytes memory data) public view returns (string memory) {
    (bytes memory data1_recovered, bytes memory data2_recovered) = abi.decode(data, (bytes, bytes));
    return string(abi.encodePacked(data2_recovered, " ", data1_recovered));
}
```